# Bukkit event for hunger?

Tags: minecraft, bukkit

I am trying to make a plugin that removes hunger from Minecraft.  However, I cannot find the event for it!

**Is there an event called when a player loses hunger?**

Something like `PlayerHungerChangeEvent`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe you are looking for the [`FoodLevelChangeEvent`](https://jd.bukkit.org/org/bukkit/event/entity/FoodLevelChangeEvent.html)

It is very oddly named, for future reference, refer to the [bukkit documentation](https://jd.bukkit.org/) :)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there is the [FoodLevelChangeEvent](https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/spigot/org/bukkit/event/entity/FoodLevelChangeEvent.html)

Answer (score 3):

You can use [FoodLevelChangeEvent](https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/spigot/org/bukkit/event/entity/FoodLevelChangeEvent.html).

```
@EventHandler
public void onFoodChange(FoodLevelChangeEvent e) {
    Player foodChangedPlayer = (Player) e.getEntity();

    //Cancelling event, thus cancelling hunger
    e.setCancelled(true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is FoodLevelChangeEvent

```
@EventHandler
public void onFoodChange(FoodLevelChanceEvent ev) {
}
```